# What is the difference between [parental-control] and [children]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-merge

[parental-control](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parental-control) is self-explaining, from [children](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children) description:

> Programs that are meant to be used when one has children (like adult content blocker etc.)

That is essentially the same.

Answer (score 6):

[children](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children) covers all software for children and people with children, parental control is only an example. The tag also covers educational software for children ([example](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/26/android-application-to-learn-english-for-small-kids)).

I propose to reserve [children](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/children) for software intended to be used by children, and use [parental-control](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parental-control) for parental control software, which is intended to be used by parents.